# Cannot display content of $_FILES

Tags: php, html

Have a look at the following code:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['email']))
{
    $expertmail=trim($_POST['email']);
    echo $expertmail;
    $expertfile=$_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name'];
    echo $expertfile;
}
    ?>

<form action="test.php" method="post" name="users" id="users" >              
   <input name="upfile"  id="upfile" type="file" />            
   <input name="email"  id="email" type="text" />
   <input type="submit" name="submit_button" id="submit_button" value="ΑΠΟΣΤΟΛΗ" />
</form>
```

Why 'echo $expertfile'  does not display anything?
Thank you

Comment: Read the docs `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: @AbraCadaver Do put that in the form of an answer and you're guaranteed a +1 from me ;)

Comment: As I see, it is so easy for some of you to downvote someone without thinking a lot. I've spent many hours to find a solution; however that was not possible. Only then, I decided to ask a question. The worse is I still have no solution!!

Answer (score 4):

[POST Method Uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) gives all the information you need to handle file uploads in PHP.  For your case you need: `enctype="multipart/form-data"`:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post" name="users" id="users" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

As Salman A points out, you will also need to check to see if a file was uploaded.

Comment: I'm a man of my [words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25813500/cannot-display-content-of-files#comment40379727_25813500) ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem remains even after adding enctype! Any other suggestion?

Comment: Not `echo $expertfile;` but `echo "<img src=\"$expertfile\">";` @ILIAS